# How to write Celery worker/tasks in another language (not Python)?

Tags: java, php, python, celery

I know that [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org) worker can receive messages in [Message Protocol v2](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html) format. And that protocol supports for multiple languages via the **lang** header:

```
...
application_headers={
    'lang': 'py',
    'task': 'proj.tasks.add',
    ...
}
...
```

In [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html) is written that worker may redirect the message to a worker that supports the language and there is no information about how worker or task can be written for example in Java, PHP etc.

Comment: Have you got any more information on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

GoCelery is supposed to do that. However, it's literally got [issues](https://github.com/gocelery/gocelery/issues) I was looking for other examples when I found your question.